# Error: c# member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: xmlserializer, serializable

this is XML

```
<TEST ID=1 TITLE="HELLO" TEST=false/>
```

this file is XmlSerializer

```
[Serializable]
[XxmlRoot(ElementName = "TEST"]
public class TEST
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ID"]
    public int ID {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TITLE"]
    public string TITLE {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TEST"]
    public bool TEST {get;set;}
}
```

Run This Project

Error Message
 "'TEST' member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

I understand it. but I CAN NOT rename this AttributeName and RootName,
XML file is Never Change, Not my File. How can I Change this Serializable File ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename your member variables while keeping the actual XML tags the same. The `AttributeName` you have used enables this. You can actually do this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "TEST"]
public class TestTag
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ID"]
    public int IdAttribute { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TITLE"]
    public string TitleAttribute { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TEST"]
    public bool TestAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

or something similar. Your XML file will remain the same!